# How to solve a graph theory question similar to shortest-path?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm looking at several problems of similar format but different difficulty. Help would be appreciated for polynomial (preferably relatively fast, but not necessarily), and even brute-force solutions of any of them.

The idea of all of the problems is that you have a weighted, undirected graph, and that an agent controls some of the nodes of the graph at the start. The agent can gain control of a node if they already control two adjacent nodes. The agent is trying to minimise the time they take to control a certain number of nodes. The problems differ on some details.

(1) You gain control of nodes in order (ie. you cannot take over multiple nodes simultaneously). The time taken to take control of a node is defined as the minimum of the edges from the two nodes used to take control of it. The goal is to take control of every single node in the graph.

(2) Again, you gain nodes in order and the goal is to take control of every single node in the graph. The time taken to take control of a node is defined as the maximum of the two nodes used to take control of it.

(3) Either (1) or (2), but with the goal of taking control of a certain number of nodes, not necessarily all of them.

(4) (3), but you can take control of multiple nodes simultaneously. Basically, say nodes 2 and 4 are being used to take over node 3 in time of 5. During that time of 5, nodes 2 and 4 cannot be used to take over a node that is not node 3. However, nodes 5 and 6 may for example be simultaneously taking over node 1.

(5) (4), but with an unweighted graph.

I started with the problem (4). I progressively made the problem easier from (4) to (3) to (2) to (1) with the hopes I could construct the solution for (4) from that. Finally, I have solved (1) but do not know how to solve any other one. My solution to (1) is this: of all candidate nodes which have two adjacent nodes that we control, simply take the one which takes the shortest amount of time. This is similar to Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. However, this kind of solution should not solve any of the others. I believe that possibly a dynamic programming solution might work though, but I have no idea how to formulate one. I also have not found brute force solutions for any of the 4 problems. It is also possible that some of the problems are not polynomially solvable, and I would be curious to know why if that is the case.

Idea for the questions are my own, and I'm solving for my own entertainment. But I would not be surprised if it can be found elsewhere.

Comment: Your solution to the first problem is greedy, but not necessarily optimal.  Consider the case where if you take over an expensive node, you can then take over a lot of nodes very cheaply.  You won't consider that solution.

Comment: That said, these problems have an NP complete feeling about them.  I wouldn't be surprised if none of them have polynomial solutions.  And the fundamental reason why not is that in a brute force search, you have to consider conquering different subsets.  And there are 2^n subsets in that naive search space.

Comment: I did not understand the full question but as it is a constraint optimisation problem. You can look at Genetics-Algorithms(Frame-work) and if you can encode your constraints then it will find an optimal solution once you recognize the good parameters

Comment: @btilly I think the idea is that you can take over other nodes from those nodes that you took over more expensively with more cheap method. I'm not entirely sure in the solution yes.

Comment: Sorry for second comment. 
@KhanSaab interested to know more would you mean here.
Also btilly not sure if this is NP-complete either, I can't think of how I would verify in polynomial time.

Comment: @aghx99 Whether it is in NP depends how you ask the question.  "Can you solve this problem with cost X?" is in NP.  "What is the cheapest solution?" might not be.  The traveling salesman problem has the same complication.  But the interesting and hard question is, "Can you use this problem to solve a known NP complete one?"  If I had an answer to that, I would post it. :-)

Comment: @btilly Hmm, can't just binary search over the answer to solve the initial problem "What is the cheapest solution?" in NP as well? (and if  "Can you solve this problem with cost X?" is in P then can be solved pseudo-polynomial). I wonder what known NP-complete problems would be similar? Also, you mentioned brute-forces in your initial response, what would be a brute-force to use here?

Also, I think that since the edges are bidirectional my solution to the problem (1) may indeed be correct as I said earlier. Would that change the complexities of the others?

Comment: @aghx99 A binary search fails because knowing that a solution of cost X exists is different from knowing how many exist.  So I can never stop guessing that there might be another solution in between the cost that I know there isn't one at and the minimum one that I've found.  But your solution to problem 1 is definitely wrong.  I'll write up a demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an answer to the problem.  It is a demonstration that the greedy approach fails for problem 1.

Suppose that we have a graph with 7 nodes.  We start by controlling `A` and `B`.  The cost from `A` to `B` and `B` to `C` and `C` to `D` are all `1`.  Both `E` and `F` connect to `A`, `B`, and `D` with cost `10`.  `G` connects to `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` with cost `100`.

The greedy strategy that you describe will connect to `E` and `F` at cost `10` each, then `D` at cost `10`, then `C` at cost `1`, then `G` at cost `100` for a total cost of `131`.

The best strategy is to connect to `G` at cost `100`, then `C` and `D` at cost `1`, then `E` and `F` at cost `10` for a total cost of `122 < 131`.

And this example demonstrates that greedy is not always going to produce the right answer.

Comment: Ah, I see... you are right. My solve is clearly wrong for this input case. So then solves for even this problem are NP?

Comment: @aghx99 Well NP just means "verifiable in polynomial time".  So yes, trivially so.  Whether there is a fast algorithm to calculate this is unclear to me.  There might be even though I don't see it yet.

Comment: first of all, sorry for the slow replies, I'm being faced with a lot of things that prevent me from responding immediately.
Secondly, I feel dumb for asking this, but how would one verify in polynomial time here? I just don't see it.

Comment: @aghx99 If someone says, "Here is a path of conquest of cost at most X" you can simply play out the path of conquest and add up the cost to verify the statement.  That is the polynomial verification that I'm discussing.  Exactly like how you verify, "Here is a path for traveling salesman of cost at most Y."

Comment: Oh, ok I get what you're saying. "What is the cheapest path?" may not be in NP, though, which I realise you said earlier. It's convenient to be able to verify that a solution is valid in P time though, to check the efficacy of solves.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to come up with a reduction yet, but these problems have the flavor of NP-hard network design and maximum coverage problems, so I would be quite surprised if variants (3) through (5) were tractable.

My practical suggestion would be to apply the [Biased Random-Key Genetic Algorithm](http://mauricio.resende.info/talks/2012-09-CLAIO2012-brkga-tutorial-both-days.pdf) framework. The linked slide deck covers the generic part (an individual is a map from nodes to numbers; at each step, we rank individuals, retain the top x% "elite" individuals as is, produce y% offspring by crossing a random elite individual with a random non-elite individual, biased toward selecting the elite chromosomes, and fill out the rest of the population with random individuals). The non-generic part is translating an individual into a solution. My recommended starting point would be to choose to explore the lowest-numbered eligible node each time.

Comment: Interesting. When I have more time I'll look into this. Someone else has also mentioned genetic algorithms here. Just out of curiosity how long would it take for one to learn this from scratch, it does seem difficult. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Also, would be very interested if you do come up with the reduction.

Comment: @aghx99 I think you could get something up and running in a day.

Comment: @aghx99 Or you could borrow my implementation: https://github.com/eisenstatdavid/advent/blob/master/advent.cc

Comment: I see, thank you very much. I'll try implementing now.